# How to convert coding rules (text with braces etc.) in pseudocode format into a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, text, classification, rules

I am trying to put together coding rules into a dataframe.
The famous iris dataset with the decision tree classifier produces a good classification.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/simplifying-decision-tree-interpretation-decision-rules-python.html.

The kdnuggets site above, produces an output by calling a function:

tree_to_pseudo(dt, list(iris.feature_names)) that produces an output file that looks like this:

(essentially a text output

Question: How do I convert the above text file into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    df:  petal_length       petal width            classifier_outputs (3 columns)   

    0:  <= 2.45             -                    50   0.   0
    1:                      <= 1.75   
    2:  <=4.94              <= 1.65              0.   47.  0
```

The return with the square brackets suggests the end of the row.
everything else in the curly brackets is the composition of the columns.

Thanks

Nanda.

Comment: The text output looks like this:
if ( petal length (cm) <= 2.45000004768 ) {
   return [[ 50.   0.   0.]]
 } else {
   if ( petal width (cm) <= 1.75 ) {
     if ( petal length (cm) <= 4.94999980927 ) {
       if ( petal width (cm) <= 1.65000009537 ) {
         return [[  0.  47.   0.]]

Comment: essentially i would like to take the text between the if and the return and turn it into dataframe rows